# Eclipse plugin - get position info from ruler context menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin that will essentially add a breakpoint at the specified position when an option in the context menu is selected. What I currently have is a new menu contribution which I have added to the editor ruler context menu. I can select this and execute actions, but the problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to get the position info, eg class name, line number, etc.

The following is the relevant section of my plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution locationURI="popup:#CompilationUnitRulerContext?after=additions">
    <dynamic
              class="breakpoint.ui.menu.MenuExtension"
              id="breakpoint.ui.menu.BreakpointMenuExtension">
    </dynamic>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

And here is the fill() method of my MenuExtension class:

```
@Override
    public void fill(Menu menu, int index) {
        // Here you could get selection and decide what to do
        // You can also simply return if you do not want to show a menu

        // create the menu item
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CHECK, index);
        menuItem.setText("Quick Condition");
        menuItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {                  

                ConditionAction conditionAction = new ConditionAction();
                conditionAction.run();

                System.err.println("Dynamic menu selected");
            }
        });
    }
```

I thought I would be able to find what I need in the SelectionEvent object, but if it's in there it's not obvious where.

As you can probably tell from the above code, I'm new to plugin development and I have followed a tutorial to get this far. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: This is complex and needs a lot of understanding of the Java editor, the debug system and the JDT Abstract Syntax tree. You might want to study  the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointAction` class which implements the normal toggle breakpoint action.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the pointer, I've actually come across this before. What I need is the object of type IVerticalRulerInfo that is passed into the constructor of this class. From there I can do everything I need to. As mentioned in my question I've been following a tutorial to get to this point and I think I may have gone about it the wrong way. Is it possible to get hold of this IVerticalRulerInfo object in the listener for my new menu item in the ruler context menu?

Comment: If you have the current `IEditorPart` you can get the ruler with `(IVerticalRulerInfo)editor.getAdapter(IVerticalRulerInfo.class)`

Comment: @greg-449 All I have is what is in the code above. The actual functionality of my plugin was written with a dummy UI view, and I'm just trying to put it into something a bit more usable. Can you recommend another way of adding a menu item to the editor ruler context menu that would give me the IEditorPart?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to get the active editor such as `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor()`

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I've now got access to the info I need. Thanks a lot for your help!